# How to pass modem WAN port to a soft router by a switch with VLAN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, modem

Moved from Networking Engineering.

I had a fiber modem (100M) connected to my main router through one CAT5 cable in my local LAN. Now I just built a HP Gen8 microserver, and I plan to create a software router using Hyper-V on this server to replace my old hardware router.

The modem is very far from my server, there is only one CAT5 cable in the wall links the modem to the location where the old router and the server are. My problem is I need several LAN ports (can be DHCPed from the soft router) near by the modem.

I have 2 same 8-port Giga Swithes with VLAN capabilites, so that my question is how to pass the WAN port from the modem to the soft router through a switch and one cable, and DHCP serveral LAN port back on the same switch through the same cable?

I guess there will be bandwidth conflict on the CAT5 cable, so I must config a speed limit rule on the software router right?

Moreover, my HP Gen8 Micro server has 2 ethernet ports, I made a trunk port using one of the switches, is that possible to virtualize a WAN port without breaking the trunk port setup for the speed on the server ?